# Using Bare initramfs without rootfs

Tags: linux

I am trying to use initramfs as my filesystem for linux kernel booting.
I want my filesystem to be minimal, so i only use initramfs without rootfs. Now once kernel boots it execute /init from initramfs, i tried to mount proc and sysfs in init as shown below.

```
#!/bin/busybox sh
echo "Mounting Proc and Sysfs"
# Mount the /proc and /sys filesystems.
mount -t proc none /proc
mount -t sysfs none /sys
```

what more i have to add to get the command prompt with initramfs. i got below error, when i execute above init command.

```
New FileSystem
Mounting Proc and Sysfs
This script just
[    4.524724] sh (116) used greatest stack depth: 13832 bytes left mounts and boots the rootfs, nothing else!
[    4.537448] Kernel panic - not syncing: Attempted to kill init! exitcode=0x00000000
[    4.537448]
[     4.537453] CPU: 0 PID: 1 Comm: init Not tainted 4.1.17-ltsi-rt18 #4
```

Comment: Please fix your formatting

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is that your shell script (aka "init") exits. The kernel will not run past the point where PID 1 exits. Regular init sequences solve this by tossing PID 1 around using exceve (i.e - the init in initramfs calls exceve to switch to the init in your root file system, and so on).

I suggest either adding a call to /bin/sh (bash, zsh, whatever) at the end of your init, followed by a call to shutdown (so that if the shell exits, the system halts). This will give you a somewhat usable shell to play with.

Also, since you seem to be using busybox already, it has a quite usable init implementation. You can use that to start an actual init sequence, with actual shells with actual TTY control.